# ID3 tagging of remotely stored files

Tags: mp3, cloud-storage, id3

Is it possible to change ID3 tags of files that are stored in the cloud (Google Drive, One Drive, Drop Box, etc)?
Ideally, I want to use a Windows MP3 tagging program (like MP3Tag, or similar) to edit ID3 tags of my music/podcast collection on Google drive or One Drive.

Alternatively, an online service like [rollApp](http://www.rollapp.com) could do too. But, AFAIK it is only implemented with limited functionality for free users in [4Shared](http://www.4Shared.com) and as such is not of much use.

Comment: if it ( the cloud drive) looks like a local drive or folder in explorer, then you can probably use mp3tag without any special setup. You might try it on a single file.

Comment: I have tried mounting One Drive as a network drive but editing ID3 tags works horribly slow.

Comment: @icsharp: Naturally, since it must be downloading each file, modifying the metadata and reuploading it.